# How to use jaxb customization to change variable class

Tags: jaxb

I try this:

```
<jxb:bindings node="xsd:element[@name='CustomList']">
    <jxb:class name="java.util.List" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

but generated class look like:

```
    @XmlElementRef(name = "CustomList", namespace = "urn:org:MyXsd:v1", type = JavaUtilList.class)
    protected JAXBElement<?> customList;
```

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: nope, I didnt solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration needed for change class name of your "CustomList".

If you want change type you should use an XMLAdapter

```
<jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" printMethod="com.xsd.DateTimeAdapter.printDateTime" parseMethod="com.xsd.DateTimeAdapter.parseDateTime" />
```

this is an example for DateTime...

```
public class DateTimeAdapter {
    public static Date parseDateTime(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(s).getTime();
    }
    public static String printDateTime(Date dt) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(dt);
        return DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(cal);
    }
}
```